# Reducing object of functions to new typed object with varying function signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm refactoring some React/Redux code that used to use an old pattern into a more "hooks" based pattern, using TypeScript.

In the old pattern, we'd use "class-based" components, and pass in their "dispatch" functions using `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  doSomething: someSomethingAction,
  doSomething: doSomethingElseAction
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    ...
  };
};

export const MyComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UnconnectedComponent);
```

Then in the component, you'd access `this.props.doSomething()`, etc.

In the new pattern, I'd do this:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const doSomething = (...args: any[]) => dispatch(doSomethingAction(...args));
const doSomethingElse = (...args: any[]) => dispatch(doSomethingElseAction(...args));
```

I'd love to refactor this, so that it doesn't have to be so damn verbose (some component have like 20 of these functions), and also so that I can automatically get the types of the `action` function (eg `doSomethingAction`) to be the types of the "dispatched" function (eg `doSomething`).

The former is easy enough. I'd just do something like this:

```
const useActions = (actionObj) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return Object.keys(actionObj).reduce((acc, key) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key.replace(/Action$/g, '')]: (...args) => dispatch(actionObj[key](...args))
  }, {});
}
```

The trouble is, the above is JavaScript, and doesn't handle any of the typing. I'd love to have a function that could "extract" these types automatically, so that the extracted "dispatch" functions pulled from the resulting object know how many args, and of what types, to take.

I was thinking maybe I could do something like the below, but I'm running into issues and don't really know if this is possible, so I'd appreciate any feedback:

```
const useActions = (actionObj: Record<string, (...args: unknown[]) => unknown>) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return Object.keys(actionObj).reduce((acc, key) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key.replace(/Action$/g, '']: (...args) => (dispatch(actionObj[key](...args)) as Parameters<typeof actionObj[key]>)
  }, {});
}
```

Thoughts? Is this even possible with individual actions? Eg a `const doSomething = useDispatchAction(doSomethingAction);` that extracts the right parameter types?

**EDIT**

I suppose this question could abstract away more of the React context.

Basically, the question is, with a function like the below, can I create A) a "wrapping" function which returns a new function which takes the same args as the original, automatically, B) even better, a "wrapping" function which takes multiple functions (as an array or object), "wraps" them as in the above, and returns a set of functions which have typed arguments:

```
const exampleFunc = (first: string, second: number) => `${first} #${second}`;

// how to define?
const wrapperTypeOne = '???';

const wrapped = wrapperTypeOne(exampleFunc);
wrapped('hello', 2); // works
wrapped('hello'); // fails type check
wrapped(2, 2); // fails type check

// Version 2 - how to define
const wrapperTypeTwo = '???'; 
const wrapped2 = wrapperTypeTwo({ exampleFunc });

// Or, allow for name modification, but that's the easy part
wrapped2.exampleFunc('hello', 2); // works
wrapped2.exampleFunc('hello'); // fails type check
wrapped2.exampleFunc(2, 2); // fails type check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're willing to put up with a little bit of `any` trust-me-I-know-what-I'm-doing in the *construction* of this type, both *sides* of the construction can be well-typed:

```js
type ActionsProps<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as ActionlessKey<K & string>]: T[K]
}

type ActionlessKey<K extends string> = K extends `${infer V}Action` ? V : never;

function useActions<T extends object>(actions: T): ActionsProps<T> {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const keys = Object.keys(actions);
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key.replace(/Action$/g, '')]: (...args: any[]) => (dispatch((actions as any)[key](...args)))
  }), {}) as any;
}
```

Usage is as simple as:

```js
enum Dinosaur {
  T_REX,
  STEGOSAURUS,
  PTERODACTYL,
  TRICERATOPS,
  // There are obviously _MANY_ more!
}
type UserInfoActionArgs = { name: string, age: number, favoriteDinosaur: Dinosaur };
const userInfoAction = ({name, age, favoriteDinosaur}: UserInfoActionArgs) => {
  return { payload: { name, age, favoriteDino: favoriteDinosaur } };
}


const myActions = useActions({
  fooAction: (x: number, y: number) => ({payload: x + y}),
  barAction: userInfoAction
})
myActions.foo(3, 4);
myActions.bar({ name: 'Sam', age: 3 });
// That's an error - must remember the favorite DINOSAUR!
```

Comment: Wow. This is some beautiful magic. So for my own understanding, ActionProps is taking the type of the passed in actions object, and returning a new object with the modified keys, pointing to the existing types of the actions values? Fascinating that there's no need for `Parameters`, and that it works even for actions that take no args.

Comment: There's no need for `Parameters` because we don't actually want to _manipulate_ the function types, just use them as-is.